# Spring MVC 5 ResultMatcher jsonPath null value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

After upgrading my rest service from Spring Boot 1.5.10 to 2.0.0 I encountered my tests failing which passed before.

Following Scenario:

```
import org.mockito.internal.matchers.Null;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;

...

.andExpect(jsonPath("img").value(Null.NULL))
```

Fails now in Spring MVC 5 with following message:

> java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "img"
>   Expected :isNull()
>   Actual   :null

What is the correct way in Spring MVC 5 to assert that the value of the `jsonPath` is `null`?

Comment: Are you using jayway lib for jsonpath? Can you please show the name package name for jsonpath ?

Comment: I am using `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;`

Comment: alternate way is to use new JsonPathExpectationsHelper("$.img").assertValueIsEmpty(jsonContent);

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Answering my own question as I found the solution by myself.

You have to use the correct Matcher, in my case `org.hamcrest.core.IsNull`

So I had to change to

```
import org.hamcrest.core.IsNull;
...
andExpect(jsonPath("img").value(IsNull.nullValue()))
```

Answer (score 4):

## **April 2022**, **Hamcrest 2.2**

[nullValue()](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#nullValue--) is a standalone static method importable by `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue`.

So, updated solution resolves to

```java
static import org.hamcrest.core.nullValue;
...
andExpect(jsonPath("img").value(nullValue()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use content().srtring(Matcher matcher) and then use IsEmptyString matcher

```
result.andDo(print())
      .andExpect(status().isNoContent())
      .andExpect(content().string(IsEmptyString.isEmptyOrNullString()));
```

Comment: It's not the same.
Your solution will verify that response doesn't have **any content at all**, but the required solution, which was provided by @mrkernelpanic himself, should verify that **only one field** from the response Json object is NULL.
It's two definitely different checks.

Comment: `isEmptyOrNullString()` was deprecated you should use `emptyOrNullString()`